# Darkness Point of Origin on an Object

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

If the Darkness spell is cast on a point that is on the end of a 10 foot pole or a glaive or some other large object, does the center of the sphere stick to that end or does it emanate from the "center" of that object?